# grep not behaving as expected

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

Why is

```
lsmod |grep --color=auto pcs*
```

also matching `pcgss`?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `s*` tells grep to match `s` *zero* or more times. You seem to confuse regex and file search patterns. If you need to output only lines with `pcs` + something, just use `pcs` as regex pattern:

```
lsmod |grep --color=auto pcs
```

Comment: ah okay... * will also match it ZERO times :-D

Comment: @canoodle Instead of `*` you could use `+`.

Answer (score 2):

`man grep`:

```
A  regular  expression  may  be  followed  by one of several repetition
operators:
       *      The preceding item will be matched zero or more times.
       +      The preceding item will be matched one or more times.
```